# Model formula for Multilevel Model where different sets of predictors are used for random intercept and random slope

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I have been searching for many web sources just to try to get any information on this issue. I am working on a **two-level multilevel model**.

#### Problem Background

In level one, I have one response variable with one predictor variable. Therefore, I have **one intercept** and **one slope coefficient** at this level.
In level two, I have **one model that predicts the level-one intercept** and **another model that predicts the level-one slope**. In my study, **I will be using different predictors in both level-two models**. Nearly all tutorials in the internet and the books I have read assume the same level-two predictors are being used to predict the level-one intercept and level-one slope.

#### Question

How should I specify my model in r? (Packages in use: `lmerTest`, `blmer`, and `brms`. They all use the same model formulation)

**List of Variables** 
`y` - level 1 response variable 
`L1x` - level 1 predictor variable 
`L2a` - level 2 predictor for the level 1 intercept 
`L2b` - level 2 predictor for the level 1 slope 
`g` - grouping variable

#### What I Know

Null Model: This is simple. I think I have done it correctly.

```r
y ~ (1|g)
```

Random Intercept Model: I am pretty sure this is correct too. `L1x` will be a fixed effect predictor and this only allows the incept to be varying across the different groups.

```r
y ~ L1x + (1 | g)
```

#### What I Don't Know

How do I make a formula for random intercept and random slope and beyond? I know that when you have the same level-two predictors for both the intercept and the slope, it is

```r
y ~ L1x + (L2b | g)
```

But to my understanding, this assumes `L2b` to be the level-two predictor of both Level-one intercept and slope. How do I formulate my model when the level-two predictors for level-one intercept and slope are different? I hope my question makes sense to everybody.

#### Note:

This is my first time posting. Please let me know what I should do to make the question clearer to you. Thank you.

I could not figure out how to use LaTex code here, so I am adding the model as images.

**Level One Model**
[image: level 1 model]

**Level Two Models**
[image: level 2 model 1]
[image: level 2 model 2]

Comment: You may find this forum useful for this sort of question: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/c/interfaces/brms/36

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your information. I will post there too. brms and lmerTest package use the same model formulation.